# Debugging SF API

Tags: soap-api, debugging

I'm calling the SF SOAP API from 3rd party system 
e.g. services/data/v25.0/sobjects/Account/
I'm facing a problem which I would like to debug.
How can I debug the API and see what am I being sent?

Comment: I am confused .Looks like you are using REST API of SFDC?

Comment: Have you tried setting up the Debug logs ?

Comment: You are right, my typo, I was thinking of multiple things at the same time :-) its the REST API but my question still stands... I have set up the debug logs but I am not seeing the API's logs

Answer (score 1):

Use [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/) if you need to debug the REST API.

If you are using callout using http you can inspect the body and the header of the response .

For SOAP AP1 use SOAPUI to debug by creating a project with WSDL .(The request and response XML will be auto generated )

Update:

Standard REST API its difficult to figure out whole log.The response can be viewed from workbench .